# Can autocapitalize be turned off with javascript in mobile safari?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, mobile-safari

Mobile safari supports an attribute on input elements called [`autocapitalize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlelement/2871133-autocapitalize)
[[documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DesigningForms/DesigningForms.html)], which when set to 'off' will stop the iPhone capitalizing the text input into that field, which is useful for url or email fields.

```
<input type="text" class="email" autocapitalize="off" />
```

But this attribute is not valid in html 5 (or another spec as far as I know) so including it in the html will produce an invalid html page, what I would like to do is be able to add this attribute to particular fields onload with javascript with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('input.email, input.url').attr('autocapitalize', 'off');
});
```

which adds the correct attribute in firefox and desktop safari, but doesn't seem to do anything in mobile safari, why?

Comment: It's much better to specify it in the HTML and suffer a harmless warning than to do it in Javascript for no actual benefit.  You've replaced something simple, obvious and fast, that works even without scripting, with something needlessly complicated.

Comment: @Glenn: not exactly a harmless warning. You (and anyone else who maintains the code) has got to remember that this specific validation warning doesn’t matter. Kind of annoying.

Comment: @Paul: The purpose of validators is to make sure you're aware when you're using nonstandard features, so you can make an educated decision rather than using them unknowingly.  They're not there to prevent you from using them.

Comment: @Glenn: Sure, but I also use them to catch coding errors. It’s more effort to do that if I have to remember which errors aren’t actually errors. (Ideally, validators would be updated with non-standard but useful and functional custom features like this, and list them as warnings rather than errors.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be fixed in iPhone OS 3.0.  What version of iPhone OS are you trying this on?

```
Email: <input id="email" type="text"><br>
URL: <input id="url" type="text"><br>
<script>
//document.getElementById("email").autocapitalize = 'off';
//document.getElementById("url").autocapitalize = 'on';
document.getElementById("email").setAttribute('autocapitalize', 'off');
document.getElementById("url").setAttribute('autocapitalize', 'on');
alert(document.body.innerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah in iPhone 3.0, this code works great, but the equivalent jQuery doesn't, thanks a lot

Comment: Don't do this.  It's completely pointless and only obfuscates the page.

Answer (score 8):

Side note. You can improve the user experience on iOS even more by specifying the type of the input to be "email" to automatically bring up the "email" keyboard (slightly better characters for typing an email).

```
<input type="email" class="email" autocapitalize="off" />
```

[Here is some documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) on how input types can control the iOS keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

It's just as invalid if you add it via script or if you add it in the markup. It's just that the validator isn't able to notice it if you add it via script.

Just put it in the markup and put a comment next to it, like `<!-- the "autocapitalize" attribute is an Apple proprietary extension for the iPhone to change its IME behaviour -->`, that way people who look at the code in the validator will know what's up.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a useful feature, you'll just have to pick between strict validation and user experience. Personally, I'd pick UX any day.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't get jQuery to do it but plain old javascript, as ddkilzer suggested works, so I put together this function to apply the autocapitalize='off' option to all inputs with a specific class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // disable autocapitalize on .url, .email fields
  unautocapitalize('url');
  unautocapitalize('email');
});

function unautocapitalize(cssClass){
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(cssClass);
  for (var j = 0; j < elems.length; j++){
    elems[j].setAttribute('autocapitalize', 'off');
  }
}
```